# Show Maintenance domain if web app is stopped

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cdn

I  have created static site on azure account and I want to show that domain if my web app is stopped is there any way to do  that using azure cdn.

I dont have front door or app gateway

I tried using azure cdn rule but its not redirecting domain

Comment: You can do it via azure application gateway only.

Answer (score 0):

> AFAIK using azure CDN it's not supported you can redirect via Application gateway and blob storage should be directly accessible as storage accounts fronted by Azure CDN services are currently not supported.

In my Azure Application gateway, I am able to access site like below:

[image]

If you want to show that domain if my web app is stopped, you can use custom error page like below:

In Azure Application gateway -> listener add your custom error page URL which you stored in blob storage account or virtual machine to host an error page like below:

[image]

Now when my web app is stopped, or there is any malicious traffic Application Gateway will redirect to the custom error page like below:

[image]

[image]

You can create `Global level` error pages that are applied to all the listeners of Application gateway using PowerShell script :

```
$appgw   = Get-AzApplicationGateway -Name <app-gateway-name> -ResourceGroupName <resource-group-name>
$updatedgateway = Add-AzApplicationGatewayCustomError -ApplicationGateway $appgw -StatusCode HttpStatus502 -CustomErrorPageUrl "http://<website-url>"
Set-AzApplicationGateway -ApplicationGateway $appgw
```

***Output***:

```
ResourceGroupName Name Location Sku Name    Policy Name EnableHttp2 EnableFips ForceFirewallPolicyAssociation OperationalState ProvisioningState Identity
----------------- ---- -------- --------    ----------- ----------- ---------- ------------------------------ ---------------- ----------------- --------
        imran      app1 eastus   Standard_v2             True                                                  Running          Succeeded
```

[image]

***Reference***:

[Create Azure Application Gateway custom error pages | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/custom-error)